# PostgreSQL 11.5 insert or update (every operation should add the field value)

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I use `INSERT INTO ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` to implement that if the row does not yet exist, then `INSERT` it, if it exists, then do `UPDATE`, but on every update I want to add one field's value.

Assume the table (`test_table`) only has two columns and their name is：`name` (with a `UNIQUE` constraint) and `count`，and `INSERT` this:

```
values ('postgres',10)
```

10 times，then I want the result to be：

```
name         count

postgres     100
```

how to write the SQL? Here is what I use:

```
INSERT INTO test_table(name,count)
VALUES ('postgres', 10)
ON CONFLICT(name)
DO UPDATE set count = EXCLUDED.count + 10
```

The result of this is

```
name         count

postgres     20
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sum up values you should use

```
DO UPDATE set count = test_table.count + EXCLUDED.count
```

Comment: I execute the sql but get an error:`Field association "count" is ambiguous LINE 4: DO UPDATE set count = count + EXCLUDED.count`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the schema qualification. Fixed.